# Give <nav> a border

Tags: css, html, border, nav

I am using HTML5 elements so I am making a navbar with the `<nav>` tag. I wanted to give the `<nav>` a border at the top and a border at the bottom, but the code wont work. What did I do wrong?

Here is my code for HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="css/fphmain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<header>
</header>

<div id="content">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="tracts.html">Tracts</a></li>
    <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>    
    </ul>
</nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#content {
    width:980px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

nav {
    width:100%;
}

nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add any border CSS and the floats inside haven't been cleared:

```
nav {
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
} 
nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS in your stylesheet that would create a border on your `nav` element.

You need to add CSS with `border-bottom` and `border-top` style rules that would create such borders. For example, if you want a black border that is one pixel thick on the top and bottom of the `nav` element, then you would apply a style rule such as this:

```
nav {
    border-top: 1px solid black;    /* in place of the word "black", 
                                       you can use #000000 or rgb(0,0,0) */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you don't want other elements right next to the `nav` (in other words, if you want all other elements to be either above or below it), then you can apply a `display: block;` rule to the nav, along with `clear: both;`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to see the borders properly even when they are applied to the `nav` because you need a clearfix on the nave element, due to the floating list items. Check out Nicolas Gallagher's [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you give no height to your nav you may use : `overflow:hidden;`.

It will wrap any floatting child and will stand aside adjacent floatting element.

just use : `nav {overflow:hidden;border-top:solid;border-bottom:solid;}`,

no need of a `width:100%;` for block element.

Answer (score 0):

you can add
border: 1px solid #000006;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question asked for a border at the top and the bottom of the `nav` and not just around the `nav`.